# How to allow only one UIImageView to be touched at a time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uikit

I have built a simple memory game which consists of 16 UIImageViews.
[image: board with no flipped cards]

For the memory game, you are only supposed to be able to touch one card at a time.  When you touch the card, it flips over and reveals the image underneath

[image: board with one flipped card]

My issue is that I only want the user to be able to touch one image view at a time.  When a user taps on two cards at the same time, it glitches the game.  So my question is how do I allow only 1 UIImageView to perform an action at a time, and not allow multiple UIImageViews to perform an action at the same time if touched simultaneously.

Comment: How do you detect / handle a touch right now?

Comment: I have a tapgesturerecognizer which all of my UIImageViews are connected too.  @luk2302

Comment: What causes the card to be flipped back so that another card can be flipped?

Comment: Another option : UICollectionView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the user has to unflip a card by selecting it again, I would suggest adding a property to your viewController to keep track of the `selectedCard`.  If there is already a selected card, ignore all others.

```
var selectedCard: UIImageView?

@objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let imageView = recognizer.view as? UIImageView else { return }
    if let selected = selectedCard {
        if selected === imageView {
            // unflip the card
            imageView.image = backOfCard
            selectedCard = nil
        }
    } else {
        // display face of card
        imageView.image = ...
        selectedCard = imageView
    }
}
```

**Note:** Even if a user taps two cards at the same time, `handleTap` will be called twice in succession.  The first card will win and be flipped and become the `selectedCard` and the second card will be ignored because the `if selected === imageView` test will fail.

Comment: Yes, I have this logic.  However, this does not help me with the question as to how to allow only one card to be flipped at a time.  Because initially, the userInteractions are set to true on all cards, because we want the user to be able to tap on any card.  But I only want the user to be able to flip one card.  When both are touched at the same time is when I run into issues.  This is what I am trying to figure out.  How to handle the event where two cards are touched simultaneously .

Comment: See the note I added.

Comment: By keeping track of the selected card, the code then ignores the second simultaneously selected card.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of choices.

You could put a single tap gesture recognizer on the superview that holds all of your card views and add logic to figure out which one was tapped. Since there is a single method to identify taps, you would't ever get more than one.

Alternately, you could add an instance variable to your class that keeps track of the state, and use it to set `userInteractionEnabled` to false on the image views that you don't want the user to tap.

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear,  the issue is that the user can tap two cards at the same time. I do have logic to set userInteractionEnabled to false after the user flips a card. However,  I only want the user to be able to tap one imageView at a time, this is the issue I'm having.  If I go with your first suggestion, how exactly would I handle the scenario where the user taps two image views at the same time?

Comment: How are you handling taps? tap gesture recognizers?

Comment: If you use a tap gesture recognizer on the parent view then you could set the number of touches allowed to 1 (numberOfTouchesRequired=1, the default). If you want to have a separate tap gesture recognizer for each image view then you could use the `delegate` property on each tap gesture recognizer to prevent multiple taps from triggering at the same time.